# Proving a subgroup of $\operatorname{GL}(2, \mathbb R)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification, proof-writing

Suppose that $\operatorname{GL}(2, \mathbb R)$ is the set of all $2\times2$, invertible matrices with entries from $ \mathbb R$. If
$
   U=
  \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   a & b \\
   0 & d \\
  \end{array} } \right]
 ,$ s.t.  $a,b,d \in \mathbb R, a,d \neq 0$
Prove that U is a subgroup of $\operatorname{GL}(2, \mathbb R)$

So, I know that $\operatorname{GL}(2, \mathbb R)$ is the set of all linear transformations from $\mathbb R ^2 $ to $\mathbb R ^2$ and that therefore they're bijections. Also, I know that $\operatorname{GL}(2, \mathbb R)$ has only 2x2 matrices that have non zero determinants and real number entries, as a matrix could only be in $\operatorname{GL}(2, \mathbb R)$ i.f.f. its determinant is nonzero. Because there is a zero in the c position here, we only really have to show that $ad \neq 0$, not sure about notation there. Anyhow my thought was as follows:

Firstly, note that U is upper triangular. Consider another matrix,
$
   x=
  \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   d & e \\
   0 & f \\
  \end{array} } \right]
$, then by matrix multiplication $ U \cdot x$ =

$ Ux=
  \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   {ad} & {ae+bf} \\
   0 & {cf} \\
  \end{array} } \right]
$

So, $ac \neq 0$ and $df \neq 0$, which implies that $adcf \neq 0$, and therefore U is closed under matrix multiplication. As for the inverse of U, I believe it to be as follows:

$
   {U^{-1}}=
  \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   {C^{-1}} & -{b(ac)^{-1}} \\
   0 & {a^{-1}} \\
  \end{array} } \right]
$ But I am not sure if this is right or what conclusions to draw from this matrix.

Comment: Yes, very good so far

Comment: You need to show that $x^{-1}$ is a member of the group. You don't need to focus on $U^{-1}$.

Comment: @copper.hat I'm sorry, but could you elaborate? I think my understanding of this subject isn't perfect, but isn't the goal just to show that $U ^{-1}$ simply has an inverse? As in that that is one of the requirements for it to be a valid group?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

If $\mathbf{A}=\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}$, then $\mathbf{A}^{-1}=\frac{1}{ad-bc}\begin{pmatrix}d&-b\\-c&a\end{pmatrix}$

Comment: Thanks, I see why its important that $ad \neq 0$ now, but I'm still fuzzy on what my goal should be to prove now. Perhaps my understanding is flawed, but I thought I simply needed to prove the existence of an inverse, but I believe that to be incorrect, as I don't know where that gets me.

Comment: You are almost there.  You need to show that if $A \in U$,  then  $A^{-1}$, which exists in $\operatorname{GL}(2, \mathbb R)$, is an element of $U$.

Comment: By the way, your notation in your post confuses the subgroup and elements of the subgroup.  If the name of the subgroup (or alleged subgroup) is $U$, then you cannot call elements of the subgroup by the same name.

Comment: The "you" I am addressing is the original poster, not the author of this answer!

Comment: @Badatalgebraandproofs You could start by checking if $\mathbf{A}^{-1}$ is indeed an upper triangular matrix.

Answer (score 1):

$G = \{ A| A \text{ is upper triangular }, \det A \neq 0 \}$.
It should be clear that $G \subset \operatorname{GL}(n, \mathbb R)$.

To show that $G$ is a group is really just a matter of grinding through the
definition:

You need to show **closure**, that is, if $A_1, A_2 \in G$ then $A_1 A_2 \in G$. **Invertibility** follows from $\det (A_1 A_2) = \det A_1 \det A_2$, you need to confirm that $A_1 A_2$ is also upper triangular.

**Associativity** follows from associativity of matrix multiplication.

The **identity** $I $ is a member of $G$.

You need to show **invertibility**, that if $A \in G$, then $A^{-1} \in G$.
The only tricky part here is to show that $A^{-1}$ is upper triangular.